# Facebook Connect Posting a Status Update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

HI I have got Facebook Connect working with a functional login and logout button. So far thats it, when I press a button a I want to post something to the user. Is there something I have to authorize? What is the precise steps for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to publish content to User's Feed you not required to authorize user if you use [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) for any other ways you required to authorize user prior to content publishing.

For web applications/sites (which isn't the case) there is also way to leverage automatic publishing of content user liked using [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) social plugin by providing correct [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me) meta tags.

You really need to read documentation for [iOS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/), especially [Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/dialog/) and [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/) and [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set his status thought your FB app without showing a dialog you could do it like this

```
NSString *message = @"some text";
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message, message,nil];                          
[fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self]; //fb here is the FaceBook instance.
```

and for sure you will do that after the user login and authorized the permissions .

To Authorize the permissions

```
if (![fb isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_likes", @"read_stream", nil];
    [fb authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];
}
```

Comment: ok implement the delegate method `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` for the FBRequest and tell me whats the error.

Comment: never mind i actually figured it out myself. here is the code i used:     [facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];
So when the dialog comes up how can I set its initial text?

Comment: do i use this:         
 [facebook dialog:<#(NSString *)#> andParams:<#(NSMutableDictionary *)#> andDelegate:<#(id<FBDialogDelegate>)#>

Comment: here i tried this:

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:statusDefaults, statusDefaults, nil];
    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

but when it opens it just closes right after that

Comment: never mind, please see my new question, I figured out how to open the dialog but not how to put an initial text:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655016/facebook-connect-post-dialog-text
If you answer that I will tick this and that for extra rep