# Facebook Connect Post Dialog Text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

HI I have got Facebook Connect working with a functional login and logout button. Also when I press a button I want to post to Facebook. I can do this, kind of. You see, I have a specified string that the user customizes before hand, it is called statusUpdates. I am not sure how to do this. Here is my current code for opening the dialog to post on Facebook.

I have tried this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
     @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
     @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
     @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
     @"Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for apps to interact with users.", 
     @"description",
     @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
nil];
```

in an IBAction where statusDefaults is a valid NSString. Now I already have statusDefaults, the string I want to put on the initial Facebook dialog text because right now when it opens it is totally empty. How do I do this, what should I modify?

Comment: Probably You can check out My question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/9238700/1083859 This will help you i hope

Comment: so the dialog appears but its totaly empty ? or its just the text box not contains a message ?

Comment: @Malek_Jundi it is just the text box

Comment: @R.A you're question has no relevance to mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually thats not possible , i faced the same problem and i found this in Facebook documentation

> This field are intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling this field erodes the authenticity of the user voice.

Comment: Ok, thanks and never mind. Instead what I did was set the link, picture, name etc. field. Seems a better layout to do actually