# using xcode with the FB API to post on peoples walls

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the FB API and intergrating FB so that i caqn post on the users walls when they accept it,

i have this code sao far from the fb site its working all ok but the users are allowed to enter there own message on the post box.

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes", 
                            @"read_stream",
                            nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];

        [facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];

}
```

I was wondering if i could have a preset message to appear in the box somthing like the code below.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@" My New High Score i%",highscore]
```

and locked so that they can not edit it.

Comment: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655016/facebook-connect-post-dialog-text/9655622#9655622)

Comment: @Malek_Jundi Im sure iv seen many other games and posts ect that all seem to have a pre fixed message that have been sent on and around FB

Comment: well you can check the documentation and make some research about that , it will be helpful if you find a way to do that .. but Im almost sure of my answer about this issue.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi where was the material that you found, saying that it dosnt give their free voice thing?

Comment: check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/application_integration_points/) please

Comment: @Malek_Jundi Check [This](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed) it says you out it says, you can post to a users feed without users interaction –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by using this it posts everything i need and allows the user to add there comment plus they cant edit there high score which is what i was looking for.

```
- (void)postwall
{
    NSString *string = @"I reached a score of ";
    string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highscore]];
    string = [string stringByAppendingString:@" can you beat me?"];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   //kAppId, @"app_id",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                                   @"Watch Ma Balls", @"name",
                                   @"How long can you keep out of the way of ma balls for", @"caption",
                                   string, @"description",
                                   nil];


    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```